# Is $f(z)=G_2(z)- \frac{ \pi} {Im(z)}$ a modular form?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I Am wondering if $f(z)=G_2(z)- \frac{ \pi}{Im(z)}$ is a modular form on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, given that $f: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Here is what I have so far:

**Step one:**

1. I tried to show $f(\gamma z)=j(\gamma,z)^2 f(z) \forall\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}).$  (Remark: $j(\gamma,z)= cz+d$

   Attempt: 
               $G_2(\gamma z)= G_2 \left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \right)= \sum_{{m,n \in Z \\ m,n \not= (0,0)}} \frac{1}{(m  \frac{(az+b)}{(cz+d)}+n)^2}=(cz+d)^2 \sum_{{m,n \in Z \\ m,n \not= (0,0)}} \frac{1}{z(ma+nc)+mb+nd} = j(\gamma,z)^2 \sum_{{m,n \in Z \\ m,n \not= (0,0)}} \frac{1}{(ze+f)^2} =j(\gamma,z)^2 G_2(z)$

by letting $e=ma+nc$ and $f=mb+nd$

We also know $\frac{\pi}{\Im(\gamma z)}=\frac{\pi |j(\gamma,z)|^2}{\Im(z)}$
Since $j(\gamma,z)^2 \neq  |j(\gamma,z)|^2 $ I am unable to conclude that $f(\gamma z)= j(\gamma,z)^2 f(x)$.

**Step 2:** 
I want to know if it is meromorphic at $\infty$, i.e. If  $f^{\sim}(q)= f\left(  \frac{\log q}{2 \pi i}\right)$ can be written as a series with $a_0=0$.

I am unsure how to proceed for this step.

Comment: The problem is that $\mathrm{Im}$ in there.  This function is not analytic.

Comment: can you give me more details @GEdgar ?

Comment: Step 2 ... it is not analytic, so in particular it is not meromorphic at $\infty$.

Comment: Another hint for proving something is a modular form for $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ ... instead of trying to do $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and getting something very complicated, use the easy generators $z+1$ and $-1/z$.

Comment: but my step one does not work. I am unable to show  $f(\gamma z)= j(\gamma,z)^2 f(z)$. where is my mistake @GEdgar

Comment: **$\sum_{m,n} \frac{1}{(mz+n)^2}$ doesn't converge**, the definition of $G_2$ is $$G_2(z) = 2\zeta(2)-8 \pi^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma(n) e^{2 i \pi n z})$$ Now $G_{2k}(z) = \sum_{m,n} \frac{1}{(mz+n)^{2k}}$ does converge for $k \ge 1$ and its modularity is proven on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series).

Comment: I might be late for this post, but how can one show that the function $f(z)=G_2(z)-\frac{π}{\Im(z)}$ is not analytic ?